# What influences the lollipop growth in candy-box-2

Tags: candy-box-2

I found that planting lollipops will increase the growth rate up to 100 and that you generate triple that with the dust you find. Also lolligators help make more. What else is there and how does it affect growth rate?

Answer (score 3):

The base rate doesn't get higher than 100 from planting, but you can boost this with special items found in quests. My current multiplier is 4500, from the following;

Shell Powder (x3)

Green Shark Fin (x5)

Pitchfork (x3)